# How to compare two datagridViewRows and pass it to 3rd datagridView c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have 3 datagridViews. the 2 datagridViews have a Column ["ID"] and ["Name"]

```
`datagridView1
```

`| ID | Name |`

```
  1    Juan
  2   

datagridView2

| ID | Name |

  1    Juan`
```

Now my question is if datagridView1 rows does exist in datagridView2 the datagridView2 will pass the rows to datagridView3 and if datagridView1 rows does not exist in datagridView2 the datagridView1 will the rows to datagridView3

Answer (score 0):

You can either go by the ID column (datagridView1.Rows[row].Cells["ID"].Value) or you could also use a json parser for instance (like Newtonsoft) and compare the two json strings for full validation also with the "Name" field.

Regards, UnCoded

Answer (score 0):

i would go with something along these lines:

```
// All the grids have the same structure
// dataGridView1 columns: ID1, Name1
// dataGridView2 columns: ID2, Name2
// dataGridView3 columns: ID3, Name3
// Get the unique identificators from dataGridView2
var grid2IDs = (from r in dataGridView2.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>() where r.Cells["ID2"].Value != null select (int)r.Cells["ID2"].Value).Distinct();
// loop trough rows from dataGridView1 where ID is within grid2 unique IDs
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in from r in dataGridView1.Rows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>() where r.Cells["ID1"].Value != null && grid2IDs.Contains((int)r.Cells["ID1"].Value) select r)
{
    // Insert the row into dataGirdView3
    var newRow = dataGridView3.Rows[dataGridView3.Rows.Add()];
    for (var i = 0; i < row.Cells.Count; i++)
        newRow.Cells[i].Value = row.Cells[i].Value;
};
```